# Where have I gone wrong in understanding of CW complex and Cell homology?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I seem to have wrong understanding of CW complex and it would be nice if someone could help me out.

The definition I have for Cell complex is the usual one I think. We define glueing of cells and hence define a cell complex and so forth.

Now an easy example I want to consider is a 2-disc. Homology group of 2-disc is clearly same as homology group of a point and hence 0th homology group is $\mathbb{Z}$ and every group is 0. But other way of looking at it (which I'm sure I'm wrong) is that 2-disc is simply a one 2-cell and hence we can calculate the homology group of it to get $\mathbb{Z}$ for 2nd homology group and 0 for all others.

So why is a 2-disk not a simply 2-cell? It seem to make sense to me but clearly it's wrong.

Comment: There is no such thing as a nonempty cell complex which has no zero dimensional cells. If you read carefully, cell complexes are defined inductively, by induction on skeleta. You need a nonempty k-skeleton to define k+1 skeleton.

Comment: Ah ha. The 0-dimensional CW complex was defined to be the disjoint union of points and hence I thought it being empty set was fine. Ok this clears my problem. 

Also does that mean 2-disk have no CW complex structure?

Comment: Of course it does, 1 vertex, 1 edge and one face.

Comment: CW-complexes are defined inductively. First you define 0-dimensional CW-complexes as a disjoint union of points.  Then 1-dimensional CW-complexes as 0-dimensional CW-complexes with 1-cells attached.  Then 2-dimensional CW-complexes as 1-dimensional CW-complexes with 2-cells attached, etc.  So an $n$-cell admits the structure of a CW-complex, but it actually admits many such structures.

Comment: Is your 2-disc open or closed? If it's open, the homology you're intuitively computing is not the ordinary homology, but what's called the Borel-Moore homology. Borel-Moore homology is closely related to but differs from ordinary homology, and in particular is not a homotopy invariant.